# Vizualizing speed of movement with color scale for location in Python

Tags: python, google-maps, visualization, folium

i have 3 main values (longitude, latitude and speed). Using Folium library i can map the location with lon and lat degree. but now i want also put the velocity with  color scale. for example if the speed is between 0-20 the that part of line is red, if speed is between 20-60 the yellow, if the speed is higher than 60 then the line is green. is it possible to do it in python? Can anybody help me with this? my current code is:

```
my_map = folium.Map(location=[ave_lat, ave_long], zoom_start=14) 
folium.PolyLine(points, color="blue", weight=2.5, opacity=1).add_to(my_map)
my_map
```

"points" here is lon and lat pairs. but i have also speed column in my csv. my output is like this. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks!
[image]

but i want to add speed column for data visualising to get something like this 
[image]

Comment: Please also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903223/how-to-have-colors-based-polyline-on-folium

Comment: if this is the only thing you want to do try plotly ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I thought I might as well add my own answer because the one from @GlobalTraveler involves drawing many lines which is a bit dirty I think.

It seems that indeed there is no option in folium to do this, but you can draw multiple markers instead, and color them individually

```
from matplotlib import cm
import folium

# rgb tuple to hexadecimal conversion
def rgb2hex(rgb):
    rgb = [hex(int(256*x)) for x in rgb)]
    r, g, b = [str(x)[2:] for x in rgb]
    return f"#{r}{g}{b}"

# Defines the color mapping from speeds to rgba
color_mapper = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.cividis)
rgb_values = [c[:3] for c in color_mapper.to_rgba(speeds)] # keep rgb and drop the "a" column
colors = [rgb2hex(rgb) for rgb in rgb_values]

my_map = folium.Map(location=[ave_lat, ave_long], zoom_start=14) 

for point, color, speed in zip(points, colors, speeds):
    folium.CircleMarker(location=point,
                        radius=1.25,
                        popup=str(speed),
                        color=color).add_to(my_map)
my_map
```

For this to work you will need to have an array `points` with 2 columns and an array `speeds` as many lines as `points`.
Note that you can change `cm.cividis` to whatever suits your needs (see the reference [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html))

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. but i got some errors from this part. i really appreciate if u can help me to solve this. because im new in pyhton and this task is so important for me. here is the code below in the next comment, and my error is "too many values to unpack (expected 3)". and also i want to specify limit for  color per velocity change as i mentioned in the question description

Comment: indeed there is some error in the function. however, with this method adding individually points, you get a huge map that takes hours to open, if you have heavy GPS traces.. don't know of other method

Comment: rgb2hex is available in `matplotlib.colors.rgb2hex`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add rgba values to the color keyword for each point.

Comment: Sorry to ask but are you sure? This is not documented here https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/docs-v0.6.0/modules.html?highlight=polyline#folium.vector_layers.path_options

Comment: Apologies I meant to say hex values!

Comment: I rather meant, are you sure you can specify color for each point?

Comment: Yes the trick is to loop through each point and set the value for each of these segments.

Something like
    ~~~for color, point in zip(colors, points):
        folium.PolyLine(point, color = color).add_to(my_map)~~~

Comment: here i'm using just two columns, latitute and longitute columns

Comment: Thanks !! but the thing is that third value is from current csv, where my lon and lat degree are. and i also want to put treshold for colors based on speed values in "speed" column