# How to have colors based PolyLine on folium

Tags: python, data-visualization, folium

I try to have the path of a race with different colors according to the speed (as do applications like Strava) using folium.

I saw that you could change the colors of the markers according to the data but I can't transpose it with PolyLines.

Here is the code of my visualization :

```py
points = []
for track in gpx.tracks:
    for segment in track.segments:        
        for point in segment.points:
            points.append(tuple([point.latitude, point.longitude]))

ave_lat = sum(p[0] for p in points)/len(points)
ave_lon = sum(p[1] for p in points)/len(points)

my_map = folium.Map(location=[ave_lat, ave_lon], zoom_start=13)
folium.PolyLine(points, color="red", weight=2.5, opacity=1).add_to(my_map)
```

I also have a dataframe with longitude, latitude and speed and I would like the line to change color according to the speed.

Comment: So your PolyLine isn't red?  Everything looks in order.

Answer (score 7):

folium has ColorLine :

```
folium.ColorLine(
        positions = segments, # tuple of coordinates 
        colors = speed, # map each segment with the speed 
        colormap =  colormap, # map each value with a color 
        ).add_to(base)
```

Comment: I tried to specify the colormap via `import matplotlib` and `colormap = matplotlib.cm.Reds` but this does not seem to work. What is `colormap`?

Comment: @Thomas It can be a Branca colormap, e.g. `colormap = branca.colormap.linear.viridis.scale(0,100)`.

Answer (score 3):

The PolyLine function does not have a built in method that does this for you. The color argument needs a string value: "red" or "#FF0000". Therefore the easiest way I know is to create a dictionary with rounded speed as key and desired color hex code as value:

Given a dataframe containing coordinates:

```
>>> coordinates = {'lat':[52.354, 52.081, 52.384], 'lng':[4.903, 5.099, 4.643]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=coordinates, index=['Amsterdam', 'Utrecht', 'Haarlem'])
>>> df
              lat    lng
Amsterdam  52.354  4.903
Utrecht    52.081  5.099
Haarlem    52.384  4.643
```

And a dictionary containing the speeds between these:

```
>>> dict_speed = {}
>>> cities_all = df.index.to_list()
>>> 
>>> for origin in df.index:
...     dict_speed[origin] = {
...         desti: np.random.uniform(3, 30) for desti in cities_all if origin != desti
...     }
...     cities_all.remove(origin)
... 
>>> dict_speed
{'Amsterdam': {'Utrecht': 11.17300608896625, 'Haarlem': 28.078139459927645},
 'Utrecht': {'Haarlem': 17.07939077211872},
 'Haarlem': {}}
```

Final ingredient: the mapping dictionary that gives us a desired color for the given speed, using this link (http://blogs.perl.org/users/ovid/2010/12/perl101-red-to-green-gradient.html)
:

```
list_colors = [
    "#00FF00",
    "#12FF00",
    "#24FF00",
    "#35FF00",
    "#47FF00",
    "#58FF00",
    "#6AFF00",
    "#7CFF00",
    "#8DFF00",
    "#9FFF00",
    "#B0FF00",
    "#C2FF00",
    "#D4FF00",
    "#E5FF00",
    "#F7FF00",
    "#FFF600",
    "#FFE400",
    "#FFD300",
    "#FFC100",
    "#FFAF00",
    "#FF9E00",
    "#FF8C00",
    "#FF7B00",
    "#FF6900",
    "#FF5700",
    "#FF4600",
    "#FF3400",
    "#FF2300",
    "#FF1100",
    "#FF0000",
]
color_dict = {i: list_colors[i] for i in range(len(list_colors))}
```

And the plotting code:

```
my_map = folium.Map(
    location=[np.mean(df["lat"].values), np.mean(df["lng"].values)],
    zoom_start=7,
    tiles="Stamen Terrain",
)

for city, row in df.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([row["lat"], row["lng"]], tooltip=city).add_to(my_map)

for origin, _ in dict_speed.items():
    for desti, speed in _.items():
        folium.PolyLine(
            (df.loc[origin].values, df.loc[desti].values),
            color=color_dict[round(speed)],
        ).add_to(my_map)

my_map
```

You get a folium map with color indicating the speed!

```html
'<div style="width:100%;"><div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:0;padding-bottom:60%;"><iframe src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,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" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0;border:none !important;" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen></iframe></div></div>'
```